# Is it possible for multiple users to edit the same Javadoc through egit?

Tags: eclipse, github, javadoc, egit, multiple-users

I am working on a project with a team. We want to have inlined documentation for our project that can be edited by multiple users. Can this be done through github -- make some java doc comments, commit to github so that another person can check out your version of code along with the javadoc you generated ?

If there is a way to do this, please let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since Git does not care about the type of the file you check in - I have no doubt it is doable. Nothing needs to be changed in your workflow also.

Comment: When I check out someone else's javadoc, I am not able to see the changes they have made.

Comment: You have to tell me exactly what you doing. Otherwise it is impossible to solve this.

Comment: I am generating a javadoc on my eclipse for the project. Then i commit this to github. When someone else tries to check this code out, they cannot see the javadoc comments i have made in their eclipse/ on the web.